# Как вывести список всех callbacks к определенной метки кода

Tags: javascript

Привет...Есть ли такая возможность?
Может спецефическая функция?

**UPDATE:**Можно узнать какая именно функция вызвала запрос POST/GET?
Кода много запросов разных а найти функцию бывает трудно.

В JAVASCRIPT!

Comment: если я понял ваши слова правильно то , нет через js нельзя можно в дебагере посмотреть.

Comment: Я видел вкладку СallBacks / Что-то она меня пугает...

Comment: вам лучше как-нить по другому придумать дебажить :) call stack может быть поможет.

Comment: спасибо.....Учусь дебажить....Сделайте ответов чтобы закрыть вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да можно -  в хроме, отрываете консоль, правой кнопкой мыши, log XHR, начнет показывать какая функции были вызваны по поводу xhr, врубаетесь в код, делаете в этом месте брекпоинт условный, вызываете запрос еще раз, смотрите callstack. если код вкотором произошел вызов минифицированный, то полезно нажать **{}** во вкладке sources. ну и еще как вариант временно переписать `window.XMLHttpRequest` на wrapper, в смысле создать обертки для всех методов и в них делать остановки.